# Aggregate a matrix of dates with a for loop of a vector- matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector

I have a matrix with dates and I want to aggregate that dates, by line, into periods:

```
[01-01-2017;31-12-2017] [01-01-2018;31-12-2018] [01-01-2019;31-01-2019]
```

These is my code:

```
a=[ 20170206 20170506 20170806 20171106 20180206 20180506 20180806 20181106
20190206 20190506;
20170402 20180402 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
20170228 20170831 20180228 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
20171016 20181016 20191016 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
20171025 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]; %matrix with dates to aggregate

[r1,c1]=size(a);
p = [3;2;2;3;1]; %number of periods per line

yi=[2017;2017;2017;2017;2017];
mi=[01;01;01;01;01];
di=[01;01;01;01;01];


[m,n]=size(p);
datas(1:r1,1)=yi*10000+mi*100+di;
for i=1:m
  for j=2:p(i)
    datas(1:r1,j)=(yi+j-1)*10000+mi*100+di;
  end
end
```

Ad my result is

datas=[20170101    20180101    20190101; 20170101  20180101    20190101; 20170101  20180101    20190101; 20170101  20180101    20190101; 20170101  20180101    20190101]

But I wanted a matrix like this:

datas= [20170101    20180101    20190101; 20170101  20180101    0; 20170101 20180101    0; 20170101 20180101    20190101;20170101   0    0]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and/or clearly specify the problem (what is your current output?).

Comment: @m7913d already clarified, could u help please?

Comment: @m7913d already found it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    a=[ 20170206 20170506 20170806 20171106 20180206 20180506 20180806 20181106 20190206 20190506;
    20170402 20180402 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    20170228 20170831 20180228 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    20171016 20181016 20191016 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    20171025 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]; %matrix with dates to aggregate

[r1,c1]=size(a);
p = [3;2;2;3;1]; %number of periods per line

[m,n]=size(p);
max=max(p);


yi=[2017;2017;2017;2017;2017];
mi=[01;01;01;01;01];
di=[01;01;01;01;01];

datas(1:r1,1)=yi(1:r1)*10000+mi(1:r1)*100+di(1:r1);

for i=1:r1
    for j=2:max
        if p(i)<j
            datas(i,j)=0;
        else
            datas(i,j)=(yi(i)+j-1)*10000+mi(i)*100+di(i);
        end
    end
end
```